# Why do MPP systems need special hardware?

Tags: parallel-processing, mapreduce, amazon-redshift

Why do MPP systems like Amazon Redshift need specialized hardware. Why can't they work on off-the-shelf hardware? Whereas map-reduce systems naturally work on commodity hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A *massively parallel* system does not necessarily *need* special hardware. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_parallel) includes *grid computing* as a type of MPP, and grid computing is all about running on random, off-the-shelf systems (BOINC, Folding@Home, etc.)

You specifically mentioned the idea of the [MapReduce](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/mapreduce-osdi04.pdf) framework. Google's original implementation (and those that have followed) was designed specifically to function well on commodity hardware. MapReduce works within its constraints, such as node failures, limited communication between nodes, and so forth. Importantly, the kind of jobs you can run on MapReduce are narrowly constrained. You have a map step, and you have a reduce step; both of these steps involve *no communication between nodes*. You can't have all of the reduce workers gossiping with each other!

However, other flavors of MPP have requirements beyond basic hardware. For example, [massively parallel processor arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_parallel_processor_array) are specialized ICs with a very large number of cores, arranged so that cores can have high-speed, low-latency interconnects with other cores.

You couldn't do this on a standard computer; the core count per chip is far lower, and the cores communicate differently (usually working with a large blob of shared memory).